# Problem in solving a question related to integration.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

**The question is** :

Let $f : \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function over $\mathbb R$ defined by $$f (x) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac {\int_{x-t}^{x+t} s f' (s)\ ds} {2 t}$$ such that $f (\sqrt 2) = 2$ then find the value of $f(3)$.

By the defination of $f$ I found that $f(x) = xf'(x)$ , $x \in \mathbb R$.Is it not true?If it is true then how can I proceed from here?Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both the numerator and denominator tend to $0$ as $t$ does - suggesting the use of l'Hospital's rule. Remember also that $\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^tf(s)ds = f(t)$, by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: You did well. Now, show that $f(x) > 0$ for $x\ge\sqrt 2$ and divide your equation by $xf(x)$. Now, make use of $(\log f)'(x) = f'(x)/f(x)$. You will find that $f$ is linear.

Comment: It can be found that $f''(x)$ exists for $x \geq \sqrt 2$ and $f''(x) = 0$ , for all $x \geq \sqrt 2$.

Comment: so $f'$ is constant on $[\sqrt 2,\infty)$.

Comment: But $f'(\sqrt 2) = \sqrt 2$ which can be obtained from the relation $f'(x) = xf(x)$ and $f(\sqrt 2) = 2$.

Comment: So $f'(x) = \sqrt 2$ , for all $x \in [\sqrt 2,\infty)$.Now since $f'$ is continuous on $[\sqrt 2,\infty)$ so by fundamental theorem of integral calculus $\int_{\sqrt 2}^{3} f'(x) dx = f(3) - f(\sqrt 2)$ i.e. $\sqrt 2(3 - \sqrt 2) = f(3) - 2$.So, we have $f(3) = 3\sqrt 2$.

Comment: In general $f(x) = \sqrt 2 x$ , for all $x \in \mathbb R$.